# Auth0 - Third party Application - Refreshing Token - access_denied error

Tags: auth0

I am still receiving access_denied error even I have setup the required configuration I have found on Auth0 documentation https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow#authorize-user

I have already enabled Implicit, Authorization Code, Refresh Token, Client Credentials on my application grant_types and enabled Refresh Token Rotation too.

I have tried researching more about this but I can't find anything on google as I am probably the first one encountering this? Or probably I am missing something out here.

here's the sample curl request I have

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://{MY_AUTH0_DOMAIN}/oauth/token' \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: did=s%3Av0%3A6b3f22c0-ac00-11ec-b070- 
0b6e59231b0a.LT0c0bBGB4EukRqKLcGtHtt9t%2B3YtiQ1nQ07bfKCkyU; 
did_compat=s%3Av0%3A6b3f22c0-ac00-11ec-b070- 
0b6e59231b0a.LT0c0bBGB4EukRqKLcGtHtt9t%2B3YtiQ1nQ07bfKCkyU' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=v1.MemAxcxZBez46BV3cDnUo97zIY_lfNDi15XTCDJr5tQKbrEvnZzBjiVNvtOfrny3A0QD1AsoUDLJETl3rFkzLMM'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, in their documentation https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow#authorize-user it doesn't require you to pass client_secret but it is needed when you do request for a refresh_token. Found it here https://community.auth0.com/t/use-refresh-tokens-in-node-js-and-axios-receiving-401-error-access-denied-unauthorized/79615